# Tensorflow distributed: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed

I'm trying to run my first example of distributed training with TF. I've used the example that is in TF documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed with one ps and one worker each on a different cluster. However, I'm always getting `CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0` on the worker cluster as shown below!

trainer.py

```
import argparse
import sys

import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None


def main(_):
  ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
  worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

  # Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
  cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

  # Create and start a server for the local task.
  server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                           job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                           task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

  if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
  elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

    # Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):

      # input images
      with tf.name_scope('input'):
        # None -> batch size can be any size, 784 -> flattened mnist image
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="x-input")
        # target 10 output classes
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="y-input")

      # model parameters will change during training so we use tf.Variable
      tf.set_random_seed(1)
      with tf.name_scope("weights"):
        W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 100]))
        W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100, 10]))

      # bias
      with tf.name_scope("biases"):
        b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
        b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

      # implement model
      with tf.name_scope("softmax"):
        # y is our prediction
        z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,W1),b1)
        a2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(z2)
        z3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(a2,W2),b2)
        y  = tf.nn.softmax(z3)

      # specify cost function
      with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
        # this is our cost
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                  -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

      global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

      train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(
          loss, global_step=global_step)

    # The StopAtStepHook handles stopping after running given steps.
    hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=1000000)]

    # The MonitoredTrainingSession takes care of session initialization,
    # restoring from a checkpoint, saving to a checkpoint, and closing when done
    # or an error occurs.
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                           is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                                           checkpoint_dir="/tmp/train_logs",
                                           hooks=hooks) as mon_sess:
      while not mon_sess.should_stop():
        # Run a training step asynchronously.
        # See <a href="../api_docs/python/tf/train/SyncReplicasOptimizer"><code>tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer</code></a> for additional details on how to
        # perform *synchronous* training.
        # mon_sess.run handles AbortedError in case of preempted PS.
        mon_sess.run(train_op)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.register("type", "bool", lambda v: v.lower() == "true")
  # Flags for defining the tf.train.ClusterSpec
  parser.add_argument(
      "--ps_hosts",
      type=str,
      default="",
      help="Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs"
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      "--worker_hosts",
      type=str,
      default="",
      help="Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs"
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      "--job_name",
      type=str,
      default="",
      help="One of 'ps', 'worker'"
  )
  # Flags for defining the tf.train.Server
  parser.add_argument(
      "--task_index",
      type=int,
      default=0,
      help="Index of task within the job"
  )
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

ps cluster

```
$ python trainer.py --ps_hosts=<ps-ipaddress>:2222 --worker_hosts=<worker-ipaddress>:2222 --job_name=ps --task_index=0
2018-07-06 21:52:34.495508: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-07-06 21:52:34.802537: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 6.98GiB
2018-07-06 21:52:35.129511: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 6.98GiB
2018-07-06 21:52:35.130066: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2018-07-06 21:52:36.251900: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-07-06 21:52:36.252045: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 1 
2018-07-06 21:52:36.252058: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N Y 
2018-07-06 21:52:36.252067: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 1:   Y N 
2018-07-06 21:52:36.252770: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6754 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2018-07-06 21:52:36.357351: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 6754 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:06:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2018-07-06 21:52:36.468733: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {0 -> localhost:2222}
2018-07-06 21:52:36.468788: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job target -> {0 -> <ps-ipaddress>:2222}
2018-07-06 21:52:36.468801: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> <worker-ipaddress>:2222}
2018-07-06 21:52:36.506840: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:332] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
```

and for the worker

```
$ python trainer.py --ps_hosts=<ps-ipaddress>:2222 --worker_hosts=<worker-ipaddress>:2222 --job_name=worker --task_index=0
2018-07-06 21:55:13.276064: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-07-06 21:55:17.948796: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB
2018-07-06 21:55:18.082286: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB
2018-07-06 21:55:18.082538: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2018-07-06 21:55:18.591166: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-07-06 21:55:18.591218: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 1 
2018-07-06 21:55:18.591227: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N Y 
2018-07-06 21:55:18.591232: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 1:   Y N 
2018-07-06 21:55:18.591751: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10764 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2018-07-06 21:55:18.696213: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10764 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:06:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2018-07-06 21:55:18.801080: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {0 -> <ps-ipaddress>:2222}
2018-07-06 21:55:18.801134: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> localhost:2222}
2018-07-06 21:55:18.809115: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:332] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
WARNING:tensorflow:From mnist_distributed.py:62: get_or_create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.get_or_create_global_step
2018-07-06 21:55:31.532416: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:221] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0
2018-07-06 21:55:41.532559: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:221] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0
```

both `<ps-ipaddress>` and `<worker-ipaddress>` are replaced with the actual address. not sure if this is a problem, but these addresses are in a remote cluster. For instance, in order to connect to these clusters I have to ssh there so there is additional login step that I'm doing, should that be a problem from TF?

UPDATE:
I found that when I use the same machine for both ps and worker, it works fine only when I path `localhost:PORT_NUM` for the network address. However, when I use the actual address that I use for ssh login it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was kinda silly! I ssh to the remote server using `user@example.com` and that what I was using to define the cluster IP address in Tensorflow, but it turned out the I should be only using `example.com` and the problem was solved after that!

Another thing that I found other people suggesting is that the task id should match with the cluster IP address. For simplicity, try with one ps and one worker that both are on the same machine and see if it works with you.