# Distributed Tensorflow: The worker does not responded

Tags: tensorflow

I am running Tensorflow Distributed mode on AWS instances. PS is on one machine and each worker is on a different machine. I am running in the following problem:

```
tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:267] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0
```

I found somebody already posts exactly the same problem that I face right now but his answer is not clear for me, [Tensorflow distributed: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219374/tensorflow-distributed-createsession-still-waiting-for-response-from-worker-j?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

Can anybody suggest what might be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, after I solved my error, I will share my solution. It was not a bug in the TF code but one of two things that I tried solved my problem stated above. Because I am working on EC2 instances, the firewall prevents the connection between nodes. So, I made the rule to accept all the traffics to the instances. Second, I was using only IP-address:port-No in the command line. Instead, I wrote it like this, ec2-IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2222.